# I have an array i want to sort it in ascending order using underscore js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Here is my actual code on which no sorting applied

```
        var filteredResults = [];

        vm.searchResults.forEach(function (item) {
            filteredResults.push(item);
        });

        if (vm.selectedPolicyType === '' && vm.selectedYear === '') {
            vm.filteredResults = filteredResults;
            return;
        }
```

I want to sort in ascending so i did like this but its not working

```
         if (vm.selectedPolicyType === '' && vm.selectedYear === '') {

            vm.filteredResults = _.sortBy(filteredResults, function(abc) { return abc});
         }
```

Comment: What does your array data look like?

Comment: It contains object which have name,gender,date of birth etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sortBy function needs to sort by a property contained within your object. For example, by name...

```
_.sortBy(filteredResults, function(abc) { return abc.name; });
```

Comment: Or you can look not this answer for how to sort by multiple values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426774/underscore-sortby-based-on-multiple-attributes

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of examples:

```
    var people = [ 
        { name: 'Del', age: 50 },
        { name: 'Rodney', age: 30},
        { name: 'Trigger', age: 48 }
    ];

    var youngestFirst = _.sortBy(people, function(person){
        return person.age;
    });

    var oldestFirst = _.sortBy(people, function(person){
        return -person.age;
    });
```