# Javascript sorting with two properties

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm struggling with sorting two levels. The logic is as follows. If any of the objects have a status, return the most recent object with a status. If none of the objects have a status, return the most recent object without a status.

```
var apps = [
  { status: 'PASS', 
    date_created: Thu Sep 03 2015 17:24:45 GMT-0700 (PDT)
  },
  { status: 'FAIL',
    date_created: Thu Sep 02 2015 17:24:45 GMT-0700 (PDT),
  },
  { status: '',
    date_created: Thu Sep 03 2015 17:24:45 GMT-0700 (PDT),
  }
]

var desired_result = [{ status: 'PASS', 
    date_created: Thu Sep 03 2015 17:24:45 GMT-0700 (PDT)
  }]

var apps_2 = [
  { status: '', 
    date_created: Thu Sep 03 2015 17:24:45 GMT-0700 (PDT)
  },
  { status: '',
    date_created: Thu Sep 02 2015 17:24:45 GMT-0700 (PDT),
  },
  { status: '',
    date_created: Thu Sep 01 2015 17:24:45 GMT-0700 (PDT),
  }
]

var desired_resul2 = [{ status: '', 
    date_created: Thu Sep 03 2015 17:24:45 GMT-0700 (PDT)
  }]
```

I've tried

```
var sorted = _.sort_by(apps, function (x) { x.date_updated });
```

I've also looked a few other SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426774/underscore-sortby-based-on-multiple-attributes) but can't keep the objects in place after the first sort.

Comment: Is `date_created` a String? and there is no such function called `_.sort_by`

Comment: *If any of the objects have a status* - Can you please explain this clearly? All the data in your example have `status`

Comment: sorry, if the status is NOT an empty string

Comment: @thefourtheye or I could return it as null instead of an empty string if that's easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, here is what you are looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/whxu5sea/3/

You need to filter the elements to ensure they have a status of ANY kind. Then sort them by date, earliest first. Then get that first value. In my example I assumed the dates where strings, but still should work.

```
var apps = [
  { status: 'PASS', 
    date_created: 'Thu Sep 03 2015 17:24:45 GMT-0700 (PDT)'
  },
  { status: 'FAIL',
    date_created: 'Thu Sep 02 2015 17:24:45 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
  },
  { status: '',
    date_created: 'Thu Sep 01 2015 17:24:45 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
  }
];

var x;
var arr = _.filter(apps, function(data) {
    return !!data.status.length;
});

x = _.chain( arr.length ? arr : apps )
    .sortBy(function(data) {
        return new Date(data.date_created).getTime();
    }).last().value();

console.log( x );
```

To check if it works when no status is provided: http://jsfiddle.net/whxu5sea/4/

I hope this helps. LMK if any further clarification is needed.

EDIT: Updated to get NEWEST element (last).

Comment: Apparently I only read part of your question, sorry! Working on it handling both cases.

Comment: Fixed to handle both cases.

Comment: very close! it fails to sort by date for multiple statuses https://jsfiddle.net/ts6c9sxL/

Comment: @user2954587I just did one more update that now uses `last` instead. I think it should do it for you. Please confirm before I head home :)

Comment: confirmed! thanks for this, I was pulling out my hair. Go home :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution that iterates just once through `apps`, without a filtering step. [See here for a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ts6c9sxL/3/).

The concept is that, if `status` is falsy, its date is converted into a negative number that retains the correct sort order among all falsy elements, but makes all falsy elements have a lower sort order than all non-falsy ones.

We convert the falsy element dates by subtracting 8640000000000001, which is ([the maximimum millis in a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526504/minimum-and-maximum-date), plus one).

```
var x = _.chain(apps).sortBy(function(x) {
      var date = new Date(x.date_created).getTime();
      return x.status ? date : date - 8640000000000001;
    }).last().value();

console.log( x );
```