# Underscore: sortBy lowest price unless more than 2 or of same price, then sortBy date...etc

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

So I have used underscores sortBy and I am sorting an array of JSON objects by lowest cost...which works great.

What the client also want is this:

"If two or more results are of the same cost then the order of the collection points should be by the following priority (Highest priority first)

Lowest Price (default) – When unique price
Distance from search location
Earliest collection date"

Is something like this possible?

If you had a list of 10 items and 
2 are £1, 
2 are £2, 
2 are £3, 
2 are £4, 
2 are £5 
isn't this going to end up being a bit crazy trying to figure out the sort priority?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underscore: sortBy() based on multiple attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426774/underscore-sortby-based-on-multiple-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer to a (very) similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18262813/1071200).

There is also a simpler version, [courtesy of Janet Riley](http://janetriley.net/2014/12/sort-on-multiple-keys-with-underscores-sortby.html):

```
var fullySorted = _.sortBy(( _.sortBy(list, 'collectionDate')), 'price');
```

or

```
var fullySorted =  _.chain(list).sortBy('collectionDate').sortBy('price').value();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where I would actually prefer to use [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), because it allows you to set a custom comparator function, which would allow you to sort the array without making multiple passes, or using hacky workarounds.

Here is a relatively simple comparator implementation, that allows you to specify several functions (or properties) to compare by, where if two objects are equal according to one function, the next function will be used.

```js
const items = [{
  cost: 1,
  prioritiy: 1
}, {
  cost: 2,
  prioritiy: 1
}, {
  cost: 1,
  prioritiy: 2
}];
items.sort(by('cost', 'priority'));
console.log(items);

function by(...args) {
  const funcs = args.map(arg =>
    typeof arg === 'function' ? arg : obj => obj[arg]
  );
  const compare = (val1, val2) => {
    return typeof val1 === 'string' &&
           typeof val2 === 'string'
             ? val1.localeCompare(val2)
             : val1 - val2;
  };
  return (a, b) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < funcs.length; i++) {
      let comp = compare(funcs[i](a), funcs[i](b));
      if (comp !== 0) {
        return comp;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  };
}
```

Also, [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) is an alternative library to Underscore, which has a [`_.sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy) with this behavior.