# How to sort/hide the sequence of the component according to the hash in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have come across an issue in which there is a hash which contains a `label, index, visible` and I need to order the component according to the `index` value, it should be visible if visible is `true`.

These are my components:

```
render(){
  return(
    <GroupFeaturedCarousel {...this.props}/>
    <GroupAssignmentCarousel {...this.props}/>
    <GroupSharedCarousel {...this.props}/>
    <GroupChannelCarousel {...this.props}/>
  )
}
```

and array of hashes is this:

```
myArray = [
{default_label: "Featured", index: 0, visible: true},
{default_label: "Assigned", index: 1, visible: true},
{default_label: "Shared", index: 2, visible: true},
{default_label: "Channels", index: 3, visible: true}]
```

All I can think of solving this is by using `_.sortBy(myArray, 'index')` but then how can I implement this?

Need to consider sort and visible both.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want? Do you want to sort by visibility as well as index? If so, then [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426774/underscore-sortby-based-on-multiple-attributes) should help

Comment: No, I just want to order the component according to the myArray index. Will add the visibility later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by 'hash'? Did you mean an array?

I would something like this if i understand you correctly:

```js
class X extends React.Component{
  myArray = [{ 
      component: GroupFeaturedCarousel,
      index: 0, 
      visible: true
    }, {
      component: GroupAssignmentCarousel,
      index: 1, 
      visible: true
    }
  ]
  
  render() {
    return this.myArray
    .filter(x => x.visible == true)
    .sort((a,b) => a.index - b.index)
    .map(({component: Component, index}) => ({
       <Component key={index} {...this.props} />
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Extend your array item to look like this:

```
{
   default_label: 'foo',
   index: 0,
   visible: true,
   component: FooComponent
}
```

Then render like this:

```
render() {
    return <React.Fragment>
       { myArray
           .filter(item => item.visible)
           .sort((a,b) => a.index - b.index))
           .map(item => {
                const Component = item.component
                return <Component {...this.props} key={item.index} />
            }) }
    </React.Fragment>
}
```