# Sorting an array of objects in ascending order based on two keys having different datatypes

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array in ascending order based on two properties.

I have following data array which looks like

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'ABP',
    code: 1460,
    subCode: '0010'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'GKY',
    code: 1460,
    subCode: '0030'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'CPT',
    code: 1410,
    subCode: '0070'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'KLB',
    code: 1470,
    subCode: '0050'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'POL',
    code: 1430,
    subCode: '0050'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'FVB',
    code: 1410,
    subCode: '0050'
  },
]
```

I want to sort it like

```
[
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'FVB',
    code: 1410,
    subCode: '0050'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'CPT',
    code: 1410,
    subCode: '0070'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'POL',
    code: 1430,
    subCode: '0050'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'ABP',
    code: 1460,
    subCode: '0010'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'GKY',
    code: 1460,
    subCode: '0030'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'KLB',
    code: 1470,
    subCode: '0050'
  },
]
```

I want to sort the array in ascending order based on `code` property and if same `code` exist for multiple items then I want to sort it based on `subCode` of the `code` property.

Problem I am facing here is, `subCode` is in string and `code` is in number.
I have tried using `array.sort` and also by parsing `subCode` in integer but it has returned me different number which I didn't understand.

Comment: Where is the code you used to parse your subcode coz there are different ways of parsing string to number... please paste that code

Comment: what code u have written so far to achieve this ?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/6129952/12407377

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18262813/8043806) but uses underscore.js - A javascript library which i think you would love.

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS I have tried using parseInt('0030') which returned me 30. Don't know why

Comment: @RishikeshDehariya, so what are you expecting it to return?... the parsInt() or Number Functions behave like that only as in '0000030' would also fetch you a 30, please specify wht output are you expecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could subtract the the code properties inside the compareFunction. If both `a` and `b` have the same `code` property, then the `||` operator will subtract the `subCode` property. The `-` operator will coerce the strings to numbers and it will return a numeric value.

```js
const input=[{id:1,name:"ABP",code:1460,subCode:"0010"},{id:2,name:"GKY",code:1460,subCode:"0030"},{id:3,name:"CPT",code:1410,subCode:"0070"},{id:4,name:"KLB",code:1470,subCode:"0050"},{id:5,name:"POL",code:1430,subCode:"0050"},{id:6,name:"FVB",code:1410,subCode:"0050"},];

input.sort((a, b) => a.code - b.code || a.subCode - b.subCode)

console.log(input)
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer they will be coerced to numbers because of the subtraction. `"0030" - "0010" === 20`

Comment: Right. My head is in python. +1.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to compare string value as number value (here is `subCode`), you will need to compare them by converting to number first

See below code.

```
Ary.sort(function (obj1, obj2) {
  if (obj1.code === obj2.code) {
    return Number(obj1.subCode) - Number(obj2.subCode)
  } else {
    return obj1.code - obj2.code
  }
})
```

I assume value of `code` will always be number.